# App is complaining it cannot see the mqtt server

Tags: python, docker, mqtt

I run a swarm (currently still one Pi only), where I start 2 services. One an mqtt server, (it works, have tested it!) - the other a python app, which subscribes to the mqtt service, then publishes events to the mqtt server. Thus, one stack, 2 services.

I have 2 Dockerfiles that preps the image, and one Docker-Compose.yaml (v3) file, that starts both services (1-mqtt, 2-python app with mqtt client).

The python app is complaining it cannot see the mqtt server. I am unsure how the networking between the 2 services works. Any advise to point me in the correct direction? I tried Links - but see it is a v2 feature, and now deprecated.

Here is the Docker-Compose:

> Docker-compose.yaml for STACK

```
version: "3"
services:

    mosquitto:
        image: iotplay/iotplay_mqtt
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: '0.15'
                    memory: 140M
                reservations:
                    cpus: '0.06'
                    memory: 85M
            replicas: 1
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                delay: 30s
                max_attempts: 1
        volumes:
            - /home/pi/data/stack_rhome/rh_mqtt/config:/mqtt/config/
            - /home/pi/data/stack_rhome/rh_mqtt/data:/mqtt/data/
            - /home/pi/data/stack_rhome/rh_mqtt/log:/mqtt/log/
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
        ports:
            - 1878:1883
        hostname: rh_mqtt
        networks:
          - webnet

    paradox:
        image: iotplay/python_paradox
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: '0.15'
                    memory: 140M
                reservations:
                    cpus: '0.06'
                    memory: 85M
            replicas: 1
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                delay: 30s
                max_attempts: 1
        volumes:
            - /home/pi/data/stack_rhome/rh_paradox/log:/iotplay/log
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
        hostname: rh_dev
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=PROD
            - NODE_ENV_VER=0.1.2
        networks:
          - webnet

networks:
    webnet:
```

Comment: How is python trying to access mqtt server? It should be accessible by its hostname, `http://rh_mqtt` inside python server. Is it not happening?

Comment: Include the python code in the question so we can see how you setting up the connection

Comment: Thanks @Ayushya, after your suggestion, I added rh_mqtt into the config.ini file of the python app. But then I started wondering, I logged onto the docker service (docker exec -it <containerid> sh), the ip address of the one is 172.18.0.4, the other 172.18.0.3, also tried from the one host rh_dev to ping the other host rh_mqtt, as per your suggestion, but the one cannot ping the other, and visa versa. How do I setup the DockerCompose.yml file so that is possible?

Comment: So, you are saying that with the above `yml` file and using `http://rh_mqtt` in python app, it is not working? Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The config.ini file of the python app has settings for the mqtt server, and its port, in stead of the ip address, (I tried the external address, and localhost as well), thus not http://rh_mqtt, but as the settings are below. So, I do not understand how to get one service to talk to another....

[MQTT Broker]
IP: rh_mqtt
Port: 1878